# for bokeh figure, how do I dynamically switch x_range to factor range

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to create a scatter plot.
I have data source which contain many columns, some are string, some are numbers.
I have two select to specify x axis column and y axis column.
If x axis column data is number, the plot show up fine.
If x axis column data is string, e.g. categorical, the figure is emtpy.

I tried in code do

```
if is_categorical:
    my_figure.x_range = FactorRange(factors=x_data_unique_values)
```

But this does not seems to help.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

For categorical columns you have to declare the factors to be used with the `x_range` option in the figure.
Example below, you can try it in a notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1, 2, 3], 'col_2': ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'], 'col_3': [10, 15, 20]})

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

for x_label in ['col_1', 'col_2']:
    
    if df[x_label].dtypes in ('int64', 'float64'):
        p = figure(width=300, height=200)
        p.circle(x=x_label, y='col_3', size=8, source=source)
    else:
        values = df[x_label].unique()
        p = figure(x_range=values, width=300, height=200)
        p.circle(x=x_label, y='col_3', size=8, source=source)
    show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have defined the axis type for a figure, you cannot change the axis type (as it requires to change scale type as well). To implement this kind of behavior, two charts can be drawn, one with categorical axis and one with numerical axis, and change in final layout as per the requirement

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, LinearAxis, Plot, Scatter, Circle, FactorRange, Div, Range1d
from bokeh.layouts import Column, Row

#Create the test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col_2': ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4'], 'col_3': [10, 15, 20, 25]})
collist = [col for col in df.columns]
x_select = Select(title="X-Axis", value='col_1', options=collist)
y_select = Select(title="Y-Axis", value='col_3', options=collist)

#Create intial components
df_select = df[['col_1', 'col_3']].rename(index=str, columns={'col_1':'x', 'col_3':'y'})
source = ColumnDataSource(df_select)

#Plot with numeric axis
plot_num = figure(
    title=None, width=620, height=300,
    min_border=0, toolbar_location=None)
plot_num.circle(x='x', y='y',  source=source, alpha=0.7, size=15)

#Plot with categorical axis
plot_cat = figure(
    title=None, width=620, height=300,
    min_border=0, toolbar_location=None, x_range = FactorRange())
plot_cat.circle(x='x', y='y',  source=source, alpha=0.7, size=15)

#A Div just to show error message
error = Div(text = "Y-Values cannot be categorical - Please choose only numeric columns.\
This can be done through providing right values in dropdown", width = 620, height=300)
```

In this example, it is assumed that y-axis variable has to be numerical. In case y-axis variable is categorical, an error div is shown. However even y-axis can be created categorical, with more if-else cases

Following logic changes the screen as per x and y variables -

```
def x_select_change_function(attr, old, new):
    print(x_select.value)
    if df[x_select.value].dtype in ('int64', 'float64'):
        source.data['x'] = df[x_select.value].values
        plot_num.x_range = Range1d(min(source.data['x']), max(source.data['x']))
        c1.children[1] = plot_num
    else:
        source.data['x'] = df[x_select.value].values
        plot_cat.x_range.factors = df[x_select.value].unique().tolist()
        c1.children[1] = plot_cat

def y_select_change_function(attr, old, new):
    print(y_select.value)
    if df[y_select.value].dtype in ('int64', 'float64'):
        source.data['y'] = df[y_select.value].values
        plot_cat.y_range = Range1d(min(source.data['y']), max(source.data['y']))
        plot_num.y_range = Range1d(min(source.data['y']), max(source.data['y']))
        if df[x_select.value].dtype in ('int64', 'float64'):
            c1.children[1] = plot_num
        else:
            c1.children[1] = plot_cat
    else:
        print("Y value should be numeric")
        c1.children[1] = error

x_select.on_change('value', x_select_change_function)
y_select.on_change('value', y_select_change_function)
```

Next let's show all of these in a layout

```
r1 = Row(x_select, y_select)
c1 = Column(r1, plot_num)
curdoc().add_root(c1)
show(c1)
```

Since, all the native python callbacks are used, need to use bokeh server for callbacks to work. Once we call it using bokeh server - it works well

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]
[image: Screenshot3]